Prove correctedness of connectivity of a K(n, 2) Kneser Graph
Is there any way to prove that given $n\neq4$, a $K(n, 2)$ Kneser Graph is connected if any two vertices in the graph either have a common neighbor or are adjacent to each other?
I noticed that K(4,2) is disconnected.
Background: In graph theory, the Kneser graph K(n, k) (alternatively KG(n,k) is the graph whose vertices correspond to the k-element subsets of a set of n elements, and where two vertices are adjacent if and only if the two corresponding sets are disjoint.

Well, why not show that $K(n,2)$ is connected for $n \ge 5$ as this suffices to show what you want. And indeed, let $S_1$ and $S_2$ be two $2$-element subsets of $\{1,2, \ldots, n\}$. Then to show connectedness of KN$(n,2)$ it suffices to show that $S_1$ and $S_2$ are in the same connected component of  KN$(n,2)$. This is indeed true:

Then if on the one hand $S_1$ and $S_2$ are not disjoint, then $S_1 \cup S_2$ has $3$ elements. So any $2$-element subset $S_3$ of $\{1,2, \ldots, n\} \setminus (S_1 \cup S_2)$ [as $n \ge 5$ and $|S_1 \cup S_2|=3$ there indeed is such an $S_3$] is adjacent to both $S_1$ and $S_2$. So $S_1$ and $S_2$ are in the same connected component of the Knessler graph KN$(n,2)$.

If on the other hand $S_1$ and $S_2$ are disjoint then there is an edge in KN$(n,2)$ between $S_1$ and $S_2$ in KN$(n,2)$ by definition.  So here as well $S_1$ and $S_2$ are in the same connected component of the Knessler graph KN$(n,2)$.


